# How to find the indices at which strtok() splits the string?

Tags: c, string, cstring

I was using strtok() function in C. It returns pointer to the locations at which it splits the string.

```
int main() 
{ 
    char s[100]="A B C D";
    char *p;
    p=strtok(s," ");
    while(p!=NULL){
        p=strtok(NULL,".");
        //Do something
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

How can I find out the index at which the split occurs (preferably in constant time)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the index:

```
ptrdiff_t index = p - s;
```

Aside:  Show your real code - `s = "A B C D"` won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple as described in the previous post. Strtok returns the address. Subtract the returned address with the initial address of the array..

p - s;